# Informatica scenario on accrual values

Tags: oracle, informatica

Source table:

```
header_id  line_id   account_type         accrual_tier
101          1         expense                            NULL
101          2         liability                               TAX
101.         3         Liability                              Tax
101         4.        Liability                               GYC 
102          1         liability                                C&B
102          2         expense                             NULL
102          3         expense                             NULL
102.         4       ASSET                                ABC 
102.         5        OWNERS                            PQR 
102.         6        liability                               C&B 
 102.         7       liability                               DET
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT - target table:

```
header_id line_id  account_type   accrual_tier
101          1       expense          TAX     
101          2       liability             TAX
101          3      Liability            TAX 
101          4      liability             GYC 
102          1       liability             C&B
102          2       expense          C&B
102.         3       expense          C&B
102.         4       ASSET            ABC 
102.         5       OWNERS        PQR 
102.         6       liability            C&B 
102.         7       liability            DET
```

Every header has multiple lines, and every line is either of expense  or liability or asset or owners account type. `accrual_tier` has values for all accounts except for expense. For `'expense'` it is null.

The requirement is to populate  `accrual_tier` values for all types by its corresponding `accrual_tier` value.

EXCEPT for expense type - accrual value will be  maximum occurred accrual value for lines which has liability type.

For example, For header 101, maximum occurred accrual value under that header is TAX so to all lines which has expense type under that header will be  assigned as TAX.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: What is your definition of *maximum occurred accrual value for lines which has liability type*? From your desired output it seems it's not the highest (ASCII) value of `accrual_tier`, otherwise the substituted `accrual_tier` for line 102 would by 'DET' not 'C&B'. So presumably it's some other column or columns you haven't posted. You are asking a bunch of strangers on the internet to spend their time helping you but you can't be bother to invest your own time in framing an answerable question. Poor show.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an analytic `max()` function to find the `accrual_tier` for the liability record for each `header_id`:

```
select header_id
      , line_id
      , account_type
      , max(case when account_type = 'liability' then  accrual_tier end) 
                                over (partition by header_id) as accrual_tier
from source_table
order by header_id
      , line_id
/
```

Alternatively we can solve this with a FIRST_VALUE() function, which needs marginally less typing :):

```
select header_id
      , line_id
      , account_type
      , first_value (accrual_tier ignore nulls) 
                          over (partition by header_id) as accrual_tier
from source_table
order by header_id
      , line_id
/
```

Here is [a LiveSQL demo (free Oracle TechNet account required)](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/gi8q0e9lclolzak80fandrpv9).

Note that both these solutions are dependent on the relational integrity of the source data. If a header has multiple lines where `account_type='liability'` then you may get unexpected substitutions. Likewise, if there lines where `account_type='expense' and accrual_tier is not null` both will override the original value.

### ----------

You have revised your requirement but it's not complete: you appear to be determining the substituted value of `accrual_tier` for expenses by some criteria which you have not included in your question. So probably this is not the solution you need but it's the best I can do until your post a complete problem:

```
select header_id
      , line_id
      , account_type
      , case when accrual_tier != 'expense' then 
           accrual_tier 
        else
          last_value (accrual_tier ignore nulls) over (partition by header_id order by accrual_tier)
        end  as accrual_tier 
from source_table
order by header_id
      , line_id
/
```

---

You tagged your question `[infomatica]` but I don't have access to that product; I have assumed working Oracle SQL will solve your problem.

Comment: Problem is that all these columns are calculated, they are coming from. Different sources n I'm joining those tables. So I can put Max on calculated columns in same query. That's y I asked of we can implement it at Informatica level.

Comment: Actually you haven't made those constraints clear. Please **edit your question** to include this additional information.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful please consider accepting or upvoting it. Accepted questions improve the quality of StackOverflow for other Seekers.

Comment: Thanks !   Just one change in the requirement. In case there are multiple values coming in accrual column for each header of liability type. And I want to return maximum appeared value then what  can I do.  Because Max function is returning alphabeticaly Max value not maximum appeared value.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain this additional requirement, including some sample values to illustrate the scenario and the required output derived from those values.

Comment: Hi APC. I'm sure the SQL runner is useful, but since it sits behind a registration wall, it may fall foul of the external links guideline. SQLFiddle offers Oracle 11g - is that enough for your needs generally?

Answer (score 0):

1) Sort the data by header_id,account_type in descending order (to make sure first record of each header_id is liability)

2) In expression do the following things:

- I/p Port: Header_id
- Variable port temp=IIF(Header_id=V_Header_id OR ISNULL(V_Header_id) ,IIF(account_type='liablity',accrual_tier,NULL),NULL)
- accrual_tier: IIF(Header_id=V_Header_id OR ISNULL(V_Header_id) && account_type='expense',temp,NULL)
- Variable port V_Header_id=Header_id